# How do I install Chromium from the command line?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, chromium

I have already tried using the Ubuntu Software Center, but it won't install the Chromium browser. How can I install it using the terminal?

Comment: For those of us who want to install chromium from a PPA without using snap: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-chromium-builds/stage`
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install chromium-browser`

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: You can also install it as a snap: `sudo snap install chromium`.

Comment: Hmm seems like even the apt way installs it as snap anyways?

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap)

Answer (score 14):

First get **Chromium** by typing :

```
 sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

int the terminal , enter the password if any . Then type "

```
chromium-browser
```

to launch the browser . It will pop up a notification asking to make it default browser or not . Configure it as you want and you are ready to go .

Comment: to run Chromium you should run `chromium-browser` not `google-chrome`. Please correct it. Moreover, it was already posted before. Why have you posted this answer again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error like "**E: Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation candidate**"

Follow below commands to install chromium browser to your Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Answer (score -3):

For new users who are just starting out with Ubuntu and want to install Google Chrome browser, here’s the quickest way to do it. There are many ways to install Google Chrome in Ubuntu. Some prefer going directly to Google Chrome download page and getting the deb installer.

Others prefer to install it via PPA from the Chromium build. I prefer downloading it via the command line using wget command and installing it. The command line method is the quickest and this is what this post is about to show you.

As you may already know, Google Chrome has gone from nothing to one of the most popular web browsers. In fact, it’s my favorite web browser.  I started with Internet Explorer, then moved to Firefox and I've finally switched to Google Chrome.

I am not telling you to switch, but if you want Chrome in Ubuntu, then go and get it.

To get started with Chrome, you have few options. First you can use Firefox and go to Chrome download page and download a copy there. If you’re not comfortable with using the command line, you may want to use this method.

For users who are comfortable using the command line console, use the commands below to download Google Chrome.

```
cd /tmp
```

The 64-bit version can be downloaded using this link.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Google Chrome no longer supports 32-bit.

After downloading it, run the commands below to install it.

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; sudo apt-get -f install
```

That's it! After installing, go to Unity Dash and search for Chrome and launch it.

Enjoy!

Comment: Chromium and Google Chrome are not the same thing. This would have been a good answer if the questions were 'how can I install Google Chrome'...