# Facebook Chatting Software in Ubuntu

Tags: facebook

I wonder if there is any facebook chatting tool available for Ubuntu. The tool might contain these features:

- Chatting without opening facebook.com website
- Latest message alert
- Low bandwidth usage

Firefox prompted me to install a facebook tool. I did but then quickly removed it as it often crashes!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat You can try set up Emphathy or Pidgin.

Comment: @xangua Not sure what you are referring! I need to access an API to use a tool or develop a tool?

Comment: You could, since 2009, set up your facebook account with any xmpp client. My account is still working but I don't know if setting new accounts will work. So maybe you came a little too late.

Comment: @xangua isnt their any ready made tool?

Comment: Facebook chat app, aviable for most smartphones.

Comment: @xangua no no I want to use it on desktop. On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Try http://messenger.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already noticed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat), the Facebook XMPP chat API is deprecated starting on April 30, 2015.

> After April 30th, 2015 apps will no longer be able to access the
>   service or API. This includes both access to chat.facebook.com and the
>   xmpp_login permission.

You could, since 2010, add your facebook chat account to any XMPP client. This incluided but not limited to Pidgin and Emphaty, the previous and current IM default client on the main Ubuntu desktop.

At the current time I'm writting this my facebook account set up in pidgin is still working, however I ignore the current status of trying to set up a new account.

As part of the announce from Facebook and after the API officialy deprecated, the latest Empathy security update removed Facebook chat from the recommended protocols.

> empathy (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) trusty; urgency=medium
>
> [ Alberto Mardegan ]   * debian/control:
>       - Remove WLM and Facebook plugins from Recommends (LP: #1432613)
>       - Remove WLM and Facebook from package descriptions.

Instructions to add the Facebook chat to Pidgin (should work for any XMPP client.)

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12527/easily-add-facebook-chat-to-pidgin/

Comment: As far as I remember there was a big announcement about how they have a NEW messenger api, so it may be that the chat software needs to adapt to this.

Answer (score 5):

I use Facebook Messenger for Chrome:

I has built in desktop notifications, like this:

[image]

It appears as a window, with all your contacts, and the conversation is in iOS style:

[image]
[image]

You also see an icon in the top bar of chrome, which gets a number when you have a message:

[image][image]

[Get it on the Web Store here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-messenger/mdapmeleikeppmfgadilffngabfpibok).

Comment: just a hint - you probably want to blur out the facebook stuff if you want to be a bit more anonymous on the big nasty internet....

Comment: Haha @Wilf , you're damn right

Comment: @Tim any idea how to install it using terminal?

Comment: @MikeFriedman - you need to install the [Chromium](http://askubuntu.com/q/250773/178596) or [Google Chrome](http://askubuntu.com/q/79280/178596) browser, then visit the link and install it on it. You then can install it by visting the page, and clicking the install link. If you want it as a standalone app vist the 'App Page' and create a shortcut for it, which will appear in the menu/dash

Comment: @MikeFriedman This works through Chrome/ium so it is GUI only.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend https://github.com/Aluxian/Facebook-Messenger-Desktop.

You may also consider a facebook alternative like https://github.com/tux3/qTox to chat with your important friends ;)

Comment: This looks very good. How do I install it? I do not see any .deb files or PPAs there.

Comment: You can download .deb files at http://messengerfordesktop.com/#download

Comment: This is pretty nice. seems like this uses Chrome to do its job but it's very intuitive and makes me feel at home.