# Google Chrome Invisible

Tags: google

Whenever I try to use google chrome, I see;

[image]

It does show the menu bar

[image: if I hover over it]

it just doesn't show up period, I already tried re-installing chrome.

Any suggestions?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Macbuntu theme, used the terminal to install chrome, chrome version is 52.0.2743.116

EDIT: Sorry if I don't respond in a day or two, school just started for me.

Comment: Ubuntu version? Theme? Chrome version? Steps to install Chrome?

Comment: This is so not helping! You'll need to add more information such as what version of Ubuntu, how did you install Chrome, what sort of theme or flavor you're running... etc. Otherwise, this is just another post that I would ignore as usual. :)

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Macbuntu theme, used the terminal to install chrome, chrome version is 52.0.2743.116

Comment: @CattaRappa Add the details to your question please.

Answer (score 1):

try to open using command prompt see if it works

`sudo google-chrome-stable`

You can check version installed in your system

`apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable`

check it is newer if not then update using

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

you can also try chromium browser

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

this works similar

Comment: Please don't use `sudo` with a GUI application like Chrome. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

What if you click "full screen" in the view menu?

if that didn't work, I'd suggest removing (sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable) the program, and deleting all the cache and confing files of google before re-installing it again.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Chromium as well its same as chrome by google itself.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

check this... [How do I install Chromium from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250773/how-do-i-install-chromium-from-the-command-line)