# Selenium default download directory settings is not working in Ubuntu 20.4 - files are not saved

Tags: snap, chromium, downloads, selenium

I have this simple test script, which was working before, but it is not now after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.4

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os, time

WorkDir = "/tmp/test/"
FileName = "mitmdump"
WebServer = "http://localhost:8000/"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"download.default_directory": WorkDir , 
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(str(WebServer) + str(FileName))

while not os.path.exists(str(WorkDir) + "/" + str(FileName)):
    print("waiting for file download to finish")
    time.sleep(3)
```

When I turn **download.prompt_for_download** to True  I can see previously downloaded files by this code, however I can't see the files when I look into the /tmp/test using standard terminal or File manager.

Cause of this behavior is that [Chromium is installed in snap](https://snapcraft.io/blog/chromium-in-ubuntu-deb-to-snap-transition) which contains sandboxed filesystem.

Question is how to run this test?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by following steps to install chromium from debian in [Chromium without snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/chromium-without-snap).

Problem is that Chrome version there is 83, while version in snap is 86 and I would like to test in latest version of course. Although for this case it is probably not important, it may be important for different things.

Is there different, better way?