# Force Chromium to use Dolphin File Manager to save a download

Tags: kubuntu, chromium, dolphin

I use KDE Plasma 5.19.5  (Kubuntu 20.10)
Chromium Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
Dolphin is my default File manager and I customised its favourites and use single click to open files and directories.

The issue I have (and I spent many hours looking for an answer) is that when I save anything from Chromium, it saves using a "Save File" window that forces me to double click, shows files and folders in mixed up in alphabetical order and no favourites.
[image]

I have no idea as to what File Manager Chromium insists on using and I would like to force it to use Dolphin.

Can anyone please show me or point me to a solution?

EDIT:
@Archisman I followed your  instructions by  here askubuntu.com/a/1206153/124466 and it all worked well, however even though the first instruction was to uninstall the existing version of Chromium, I now have two Chromiums one Snap and one Deb.
The Deb one invokes Dolphin when saving or printing to PDF, so it solved my problem, however I now would like to remove the Snap version without damaging the Dep ones....  Could you please tell me how to do it safely?
[image]

Comment: It is strange indeed that you are getting what looks like a GTK3 file dialog rather than a QT dialog. That you see your file manager there, is a misconception. These file dialog are widgets defined by the toolkit used, typically GTK (Gnome, XFCe, LXDE etc. ) or Qt (Plasma, LXQt). Would be more consistent if QT dialog was used for you: this is probably defined by how the Snap is packaged.

Comment: @vanadium Most GTK apps show a GTK file dialog in KDE. By default, Firefox and Libreoffice do that too, but their behavior can be changed with appropriate plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install [`plasma-browser-integration`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/plasma-browser-integration)

```
sudo apt install plasma-browser-integration
```

Then install the [plasma integration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plasma-integration/cimiefiiaegbelhefglklhhakcgmhkai) extension, and restart Chromium.

[image]

**Image**: Qt file manager widget in action in Kubuntu 20.04, with all bookmarked folders.

---

I have verified that this answer works for **apt** version of chromium and also firefox (the same `plasma-browser-integration` package and the same Plasma Integration add on). OP reported that it **does not work** with the **snap** version of Chromium, which Ubuntu ships. One can either can install [chromium without snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap) instead, or open a bug at Launchpad to let the Ubuntu's chromium packaging team know about this.

To remove the snap version of chromium, enter the command `sudo snap remove chromium`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Spiv You can mark the answer as accepted, if it works for you. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/281134

Comment: I wrote a long comment before, but only the first line got posted??...  Anyway, terminal told me that the my ;plasma browser integration' was already the latest version.   Subsequently, I added the 'Plasma Browser' Extension to my Chromium, turned it on and of, but no joy.  Rebooted twice, still no joy.   Saving opens a 'Save file' windows that doesn't follows any of my Dolphins settings and actually doesn't show my HDD on the left side panels either....  I am at a loss on what to try next.  BTW, I installed Chromium with 'sudo apt install -y chromium-browser' .

Comment: @Spiv Ubuntu ships a snap version of chromium even when one installs it with APT. The workaround is to use the debian version of Chromium using apt. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1206153/124466

I am using this debian package of chromium, and it uses the correct (dolphin like) file manager (as can be seen in the screenshot).

Comment: it worked thanks, but see my question edit above please. I have 2 Chromiums... BTW, the Deb version uses KDialog to save, that shows files same as Dolphin.

Comment: @Spiv `sudo snap remove chromium`

Comment: After running that command, I got:   error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Save data of snap "chromium" in automatic snapshot set #1 (cannot create archive: tar: common/chromium/Profile 1/Extension State/002511.log: file changed as we read it (and 0 more))

Comment: @Spiv Please ask a new question about how to uninstall the snap version of chromium  and post this error message there. I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich Are you using snap chromium or pure apt chromium? In case you are using the snap version, follow this answer to use the apt version https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386738/how-to-install-chromium-from-the-linux-mint-repositories-in-ubuntu