# Chromium Video-Call: Blurred background -> CPU fan

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, gpu, hardware-acceleration

If I use the "blurred background" feature in a video call in Chromium,
then the CPU fan gets very loud.

I have quite new Lenovo Laptop.

Maybe Chromium can't use the hardware acceleration.

Output of `chrome://gpu`

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Raw Draw: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
Driver Bug Workarounds
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
count_all_in_varyings_packing
enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
exit_on_context_lost
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
Problems Detected
Accelerated video encode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line.
Disabled Features: video_encode
Accelerated video decode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line.
Disabled Features: video_decode
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Mesa drivers in Linux handle varyings without static use incorrectly: 333885
Applied Workarounds: count_all_in_varyings_packing
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
Expose WebGL's disjoint_timer_query extensions on platforms with site isolation: 808744, 870491
Applied Workarounds: enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
Some drivers can't recover after OUT_OF_MEM and context lost: 893177
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
ANGLE Features
allow_compressed_formats (Frontend workarounds): Enabled: true
Allow compressed formats
disable_anisotropic_filtering (Frontend workarounds): Disabled
Disable support for anisotropic filtering
disable_program_binary (Frontend features) anglebug:5007: Disabled: IsPowerVrRogue(functions)
Disable support for GL_OES_get_program_binary
disable_program_caching_for_transform_feedback (Frontend workarounds): Disabled: IsAndroid() && isQualcomm
On some GPUs, program binaries don't contain transform feedback varyings
enableCompressingPipelineCacheInThreadPool (Frontend workarounds) anglebug:4722: Disabled: false
Enable compressing pipeline cache in thread pool.
enableProgramBinaryForCapture (Frontend features) anglebug:5658: Disabled
Even if FrameCapture is enabled, enable GL_OES_get_program_binary
enable_capture_limits (Frontend features) anglebug:5750: Disabled
Set the context limits like frame capturing was enabled
forceInitShaderVariables (Frontend features): Disabled
Force-enable shader variable initialization
forceRobustResourceInit (Frontend features) anglebug:6041: Disabled
Force-enable robust resource init
lose_context_on_out_of_memory (Frontend workarounds): Enabled: true
Some users rely on a lost context notification if a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error occurs
scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args (Frontend workarounds) 1165751: Disabled: false
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent
add_and_true_to_loop_condition (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
Calculation of loop conditions in for and while loop has bug
adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer (OpenGL workarounds) 830046: Enabled: IsLinux() || (IsAndroid() && isNvidia) || (IsWindows() && isNvidia) || (IsApple() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_ES)
Many platforms have issues with blitFramebuffer when the parameters are large.
allow_clear_for_robust_resource_init (OpenGL workarounds) 883276: Disabled: IsApple()
Using glClear for robust resource initialization is buggy on some drivers and leads to texture corruption. Default to data uploads except on MacOS where it is very slow.
allow_etc_formats (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: isIntel && !IsSandyBridge(device) && !IsIvyBridge(device) && !IsHaswell(device)
Enable ETC2/EAC on desktop OpenGL
always_call_use_program_after_link (OpenGL workarounds) 110263: Enabled: true
Always call useProgram after a successful link to avoid a driver bug
avoid_1_bit_alpha_texture_formats (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isAMD
Issue with 1-bit alpha framebuffer formats
avoid_dxt1_srgb_texture_format (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled
Replaces DXT1 sRGB with DXT1 sRGB Alpha as a driver bug workaround.
bind_transform_feedback_buffer_before_bind_buffer_range (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:5140: Disabled: IsApple()
Bind transform feedback buffers to the generic binding point before calling glBindBufferBase or glBindBufferRange.
chunked_texture_upload (OpenGL workarounds) 1181068: Disabled: IsApple()
Upload texture data in <120kb chunks to work around Mac driver hangs and crashes.
clamp_array_access (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:2978: Disabled: IsAndroid() || isAMD || !functions->hasExtension("GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior")
Clamp uniform array access to avoid reading invalid memory.
clamp_frag_depth (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isNvidia
gl_FragDepth is not clamped correctly when rendering to a floating point depth buffer
clamp_msc_rate (OpenGL workarounds) 1042393: Disabled: IsLinux() && IsWayland()
Some drivers return bogus values for GetMscRate, so we clamp it to 30Hz
clamp_point_size (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: IsAndroid() || isNvidia
The point size range reported from the API is inconsistent with the actual behavior
clear_to_zero_or_one_broken (OpenGL workarounds) 710443: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 12, 6)
Clears when the clear color is all zeros or ones do not work.
clip_src_region_for_blitframebuffer (OpenGL workarounds) 830046: Disabled: IsApple() || (IsLinux() && isAMD)
Issues with blitFramebuffer when the parameters don't match the framebuffer size.
decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4646: Disabled: IsApple()
Decode and encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures.
disable_blend_func_extended (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1085: Enabled: isAMD || isIntel
ARB_blend_func_extended does not pass the tests
disable_draw_buffers_indexed (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: IsWindows() && isAMD
Disable OES_draw_buffers_indexed extension.
disable_gpu_switching_support (OpenGL workarounds) 1091824: Disabled: isDualGPUMacWithNVIDIA
Disable GPU switching support (use only the low-power GPU) on older MacBook Pros.
disable_mutlisampled_render_to_texture (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:2894: Disabled: IsAndroid() || isAdreno4xxOnAndroidLessThan51 || isAdreno4xxOnAndroid70 || isAdreno5xxOnAndroidLessThan70 || isAdreno5xxOnAndroid71 || isLinuxVivante
Many drivers have bugs when using GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture
disable_native_parallel_compile (OpenGL workarounds) 1094869: Disabled: isTSANBuild && IsLinux() && isNvidia
Do not use native KHR_parallel_shader_compile even when available.
disable_semaphore_fd (OpenGL workarounds) 1046462: Disabled: IsLinux() && isAMD && isMesa && mesaVersion < (std::array<int, 3>{19, 3, 5})
Disable GL_EXT_semaphore_fd extension
disable_sync_control_support (OpenGL workarounds) 1137851: Enabled: IsLinux() && isIntel && isMesa && mesaVersion[0] == 20
Speculative fix for issues on Linux/Wayland where exposing GLX_OML_sync_control renders Chrome unusable
disable_timestamp_queries (OpenGL workarounds) 811661: Disabled: (IsLinux() && isVMWare) || (IsAndroid() && isNvidia) || (IsAndroid() && GetAndroidSdkLevel() < 27 && IsAdreno5xxOrOlder(functions)) || (IsAndroid() && IsMaliT8xxOrOlder(functions)) || (IsAndroid() && IsMaliG31OrOlder(functions))
Disable GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query extension
disable_worker_contexts (OpenGL workarounds) 849576: Disabled: (IsWindows() && (isIntel || isAMD)) || (IsLinux() && isNvidia) || IsIOS() || IsAndroid() || IsAndroidEmulator(functions)
Some tests have been seen to fail using worker contexts
do_while_glsl_causes_gpu_hang (OpenGL workarounds) 644669: Disabled: IsApple() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 11, 0)
Some GLSL constructs involving do-while loops cause GPU hangs
does_srgb_clears_on_linear_framebuffer_attachments (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: isIntel || isAMD
Issue clearing framebuffers with linear attachments when GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB is enabled
dont_initialize_uninitialized_locals (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:2046: Disabled: IsAndroid() && isQualcomm
Initializing uninitialized locals caused odd behavior in a few WebGL 2 tests
dont_relink_programs_in_parallel (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3045: Disabled: IsAndroid() || (IsWindows() && isIntel)
Relinking a program in parallel is buggy
dont_use_loops_to_initialize_variables (OpenGL workarounds) 809422: Disabled: (IsAndroid() && isQualcomm) || (isIntel && IsApple())
For loops used to initialize variables hit native GLSL compiler bugs
emulate_abs_int_function (OpenGL workarounds) 642227: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
abs(i) where i is an integer returns unexpected result
emulate_atan_2_float (OpenGL workarounds) 672380: Disabled: isNvidia
atan(y, x) may return a wrong answer
emulate_copyteximage2d_from_renderbuffers (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4674: Disabled: IsApple() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_ES && !(isAMD && IsWindows())
CopyTexImage2D spuriously returns errors on iOS when copying from renderbuffers.
emulate_immutable_compressed_texture_3d (OpenGL workarounds) 1060012: Disabled: isQualcomm
Use non-immutable texture allocation to work around a driver bug.
emulate_isnan_float (OpenGL workarounds) 650547: Disabled: isIntel && IsApple() && IsSkylake(device) && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 13, 2)
Using isnan() on highp float will get wrong answer
emulate_max_vertex_attrib_stride (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1936: Disabled: IsLinux() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isAMD
Some drivers return 0 when MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_STRIED queried
emulate_pack_skip_rows_and_pack_skip_pixels (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4849: Disabled: IsApple() && (isAMD || isIntel || isNvidia)
GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS and GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS are ignored in Apple's OpenGL driver.
emulate_primitive_restart_fixed_index (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3997: Disabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && functions->isAtLeastGL(gl::Version(3, 1)) && !functions->isAtLeastGL(gl::Version(4, 3))
When GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX is not available, emulate it with GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART and glPrimitiveRestartIndex.
finish_does_not_cause_queries_to_be_available (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isNvidia
glFinish doesn't cause all queries to report available result
flush_before_delete_texture_if_copied_to (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4267: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
Some drivers track CopyTex{Sub}Image texture dependencies incorrectly. Flush before glDeleteTextures in this case
flush_on_framebuffer_change (OpenGL workarounds) 1181068: Disabled: IsApple() && Has9thGenIntelGPU(systemInfo)
Switching framebuffers without a flush can lead to crashes on Intel 9th Generation GPU Macs.
init_fragment_output_variables (OpenGL workarounds) 1171371: Disabled: IsAdreno42xOr3xx(functions)
No init gl_FragColor causes context lost
initialize_current_vertex_attributes (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isNvidia
During initialization, assign the current vertex attributes to the spec-mandated defaults
keep_buffer_shadow_copy (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: !CanMapBufferForRead(functions)
Maintain a shadow copy of buffer data when the GL API does not permit reading data back.
max_3d_array_texture_size_1024 (OpenGL workarounds) 927470: Disabled: limitMaxTextureSize
Limit max 3d texture size and max array texture layers to 1024 to avoid system hang
max_msaa_sample_count_4 (OpenGL workarounds) 797243: Disabled: IsAndroid() || (IsApple() && (isIntel || isAMD || isNvidia))
Various rendering bugs have been observed when using higher MSAA counts
max_texture_size_limit_4096 (OpenGL workarounds) 927470: Disabled: IsAndroid() || limitMaxTextureSize
Limit max texture size to 4096 to avoid frequent out-of-memory errors
pack_last_row_separately_for_padding_inclusion (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1512: Disabled: IsApple() || isNvidia
When uploading textures from an pack buffer, some drivers count an extra row padding
pack_overlapping_rows_separately_pack_buffer (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isNvidia
In the case of packing to a pixel pack buffer, pack overlapping rows row by row
pre_add_texel_fetch_offsets (OpenGL workarounds) 642605: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
Intel Mac drivers mistakenly consider the parameter position of nagative vaule as invalid even if the sum of position and offset is in range, so we need to add workarounds by rewriting texelFetchOffset(sampler, position, lod, offset) into texelFetch(sampler, position + offset, lod).
promote_packed_formats_to_8_bit_per_channel (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:5469: Disabled: IsApple() && hasAMD
Packed color formats are buggy on Macs with AMD GPUs
query_counter_bits_generates_errors (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3027: Disabled: IsNexus5X(vendor, device)
Drivers generate errors when querying the number of bits in timer queries
read_pixels_using_implementation_color_read_format (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4214: Disabled: !isIntel && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_ES && functions->isAtLeastGLES(gl::Version(3, 1)) && functions->hasGLESExtension("GL_EXT_texture_norm16")
Quite some OpenGL ES drivers don't implement readPixels for RGBA/UNSIGNED_SHORT from EXT_texture_norm16 correctly
reapply_ubo_bindings_after_using_binary_program (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1637: Disabled: isAMD || IsAndroid()
Some drivers forget about UBO bindings when using program binaries
regenerate_struct_names (OpenGL workarounds) 403957: Disabled: IsApple()
All Mac drivers do not handle struct scopes correctly. This workaround overwrites a structname with a unique prefix.
remove_dynamic_indexing_of_swizzled_vector (OpenGL workarounds) 709351: Disabled: IsApple() || IsAndroid() || IsWindows()
Dynamic indexing of swizzled l-values doesn't work correctly on various platforms.
remove_invarient_and_centroid_for_essl3 (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: functions->isAtMostGL(gl::Version(4, 1)) || (functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isAMD)
Fix spec difference between GLSL 4.1 or lower and ESSL3
reset_teximage2d_base_level (OpenGL workarounds) 705865: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel && GetMacOSVersion() >= OSVersion(10, 12, 4)
Reset texture base level before calling glTexImage2D to work around pixel comparison failure.
rewrite_float_unary_minus_operator (OpenGL workarounds) 308366: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 12, 0)
Using '-<float>' will get wrong answer
rewrite_repeated_assign_to_swizzled (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isNvidia
Repeated assignment to swizzled values inside a GLSL user-defined function have incorrect results
rewrite_row_major_matrices (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:2273: Disabled: false
Rewrite row major matrices in shaders as column major as a driver bug workaround
rgb_dxt1_textures_sample_zero_alpha (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3729: Disabled: IsApple()
Sampling BLACK texels from RGB DXT1 textures returns transparent black on Mac.
rgba4_is_not_supported_for_color_rendering (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isIntel
GL_RGBA4 is not color renderable
sanitize_amdgpu_renderer_string (OpenGL workarounds) 1181193: Disabled: IsLinux() && hasAMD
Strip precise kernel and DRM version information from amdgpu renderer strings.
set_primitive_restart_fixed_index_for_draw_arrays (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3997: Disabled: features->emulatePrimitiveRestartFixedIndex.enabled && IsApple() && isIntel
Some drivers discard vertex data in DrawArrays calls when the fixed primitive restart index is within the number of primitives being drawn.
set_zero_level_before_generating_mipmap (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: IsApple()
glGenerateMipmap fails if the zero texture level is not set on some Mac drivers.
shift_instanced_array_data_with_offset (OpenGL workarounds) 1144207: Disabled: IsApple() && IsIntel(vendor) && !IsHaswell(device)
glDrawArraysInstanced is buggy on certain new Mac Intel GPUs
sync_vertex_arrays_to_default (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:5577: Disabled: !nativegl::SupportsVertexArrayObjects(functions)
Only use the default VAO because of missing support or driver bugs
unbind_fbo_before_switching_context (OpenGL workarounds) 1181193: Disabled: IsPowerVR(vendor)
Imagination GL drivers are buggy with context switching.
unfold_short_circuits (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:482: Disabled: IsApple()
Mac incorrectly executes both sides of && and || expressions when they should short-circuit.
unpack_last_row_separately_for_padding_inclusion (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1512: Disabled: IsApple() || isNvidia
When uploading textures from an unpack buffer, some drivers count an extra row padding
unpack_overlapping_rows_separately_unpack_buffer (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isNvidia
In the case of unpacking from a pixel unpack buffer, unpack overlapping rows row by row
unsized_srgb_read_pixels_doesnt_transform (OpenGL workarounds) 565179: Disabled: IsAndroid() && isQualcomm
Drivers returning raw sRGB values instead of linearized values when calling glReadPixels on unsized sRGB texture formats
use_unused_blocks_with_standard_or_shared_layout (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: (IsApple() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP) || (IsLinux() && isAMD)
Unused std140 or shared uniform blocks will be treated as inactive
vertex_id_does_not_include_base_vertex (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: IsApple() && isAMD
gl_VertexID in GLSL vertex shader doesn't include base vertex value
Version Information
Data exported   2022-01-14T11:07:51.645Z
Chrome version  Chrome/97.0.4692.71
Operating system    Linux 5.13.0-25-generic
Software rendering list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/adefa7837d02a07a604c1e6eff0b3a09422ab88d/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json
Driver bug list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/adefa7837d02a07a604c1e6eff0b3a09422ab88d/gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_list.json
ANGLE commit id unknown hash
2D graphics backend Skia/97 b4d28b2f35396ae4dd69338254415066629dfd25
Command Line    /snap/chromium/1864/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --password-store=basic --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=CaptureHandle
Driver Information
Initialization time 1126
In-process GPU  false
Passthrough Command Decoder true
Sandboxed   false
GPU0    VENDOR= 0x0000 [Google Inc. (Intel)], DEVICE=0x0000 [ANGLE (Intel, Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (TGL GT1), OpenGL 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8)] *ACTIVE*
Optimus false
AMD switchable  false
Driver vendor   Mesa
Driver version  20.0.8
GPU CUDA compute capability major version   0
Pixel shader version    1.00
Vertex shader version   1.00
Max. MSAA samples   16
Machine model name  
Machine model version   
GL_VENDOR   Google Inc. (Intel)
GL_RENDERER ANGLE (Intel, Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (TGL GT1), OpenGL 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8)
GL_VERSION  OpenGL ES 2.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0 git hash: unknown hash)
GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_ANGLE_base_vertex_base_instance GL_ANGLE_client_arrays GL_ANGLE_compressed_texture_etc GL_ANGLE_depth_texture GL_ANGLE_framebuffer_blit GL_ANGLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_ANGLE_get_serialized_context_string GL_ANGLE_get_tex_level_parameter GL_ANGLE_instanced_arrays GL_ANGLE_memory_size GL_ANGLE_multi_draw GL_ANGLE_multiview_multisample GL_ANGLE_program_cache_control GL_ANGLE_provoking_vertex GL_ANGLE_request_extension GL_ANGLE_robust_client_memory GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ANGLE_texture_external_update GL_ANGLE_texture_rectangle GL_ANGLE_translated_shader_source GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_ARB_sync GL_CHROMIUM_bind_generates_resource GL_CHROMIUM_bind_uniform_location GL_CHROMIUM_color_buffer_float_rgb GL_CHROMIUM_color_buffer_float_rgba GL_CHROMIUM_copy_texture GL_CHROMIUM_lose_context GL_CHROMIUM_sync_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_draw_buffers GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_float_blend GL_EXT_frag_depth GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_multisample_compatibility GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc_srgb GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_NV_depth_buffer_float2 GL_NV_fence GL_NV_framebuffer_blit GL_NV_pack_subimage GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object GL_NV_read_depth GL_NV_read_stencil GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation GL_OES_compressed_EAC_R11_signed_texture GL_OES_compressed_EAC_R11_unsigned_texture GL_OES_compressed_EAC_RG11_signed_texture GL_OES_compressed_EAC_RG11_unsigned_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_RGBA8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_punchthroughA_RGBA8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_punchthroughA_sRGB8_alpha_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_sRGB8_alpha8_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC2_sRGB8_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_WEBGL_video_texture
Disabled Extensions GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
Disabled WebGL Extensions   
Window system binding vendor    Google Inc. (Intel)
Window system binding version   1.5 (ANGLE 2.1.0 git hash: unknown hash)
Window system binding extensions    EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANGLE_create_context_webgl_compatibility EGL_CHROMIUM_create_context_bind_generates_resource EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_ANGLE_display_texture_share_group EGL_ANGLE_display_semaphore_share_group EGL_ANGLE_create_context_client_arrays EGL_ANGLE_program_cache_control EGL_ANGLE_robust_resource_initialization EGL_ANGLE_create_context_extensions_enabled EGL_ANDROID_blob_cache EGL_ANDROID_recordable EGL_ANGLE_create_context_backwards_compatible EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error EGL_NOK_texture_from_pixmap EGL_KHR_reusable_sync EGL_KHR_mutable_render_buffer
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP ubuntu:GNOME
XDG_SESSION_TYPE    x11
GDMSESSION  ubuntu-xorg
Ozone platform  x11
Direct rendering version    unknown
Reset notification strategy 0x8252
GPU process crash count 0
gfx::BufferFormats supported for allocation and texturing   R_8: not supported, R_16: not supported, RG_88: not supported, RG_1616: not supported, BGR_565: not supported, RGBA_4444: not supported, RGBX_8888: not supported, RGBA_8888: not supported, BGRX_8888: not supported, BGRA_1010102: not supported, RGBA_1010102: not supported, BGRA_8888: not supported, RGBA_F16: not supported, YVU_420: not supported, YUV_420_BIPLANAR: not supported, P010: not supported
Compositor Information
Tile Update Mode    One-copy
Partial Raster  Enabled
GpuMemoryBuffers Status
R_8 Software only
R_16    Software only
RG_88   Software only
RG_1616 Software only
BGR_565 Software only
RGBA_4444   Software only
RGBX_8888   Software only
RGBA_8888   Software only
BGRX_8888   Software only
BGRA_1010102    Software only
RGBA_1010102    Software only
BGRA_8888   Software only
RGBA_F16    Software only
YVU_420 Software only
YUV_420_BIPLANAR    Software only
P010    Software only
Display(s) Information
Info    Display[2785062953156675] bounds=[0,864 1536x864], workarea=[54,864 1482x864], scale=1.25, rotation=0, panel_rotation=0 internal.
Color space (all)   {primaries_d50_referred: [[0.5992, 0.3673], [0.3683, 0.5771], [0.1758, 0.1614]], transfer:IEC61966_2_1, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}
Buffer format (all) BGRA_8888
SDR white level in nits 100
Bits per color component    8
Bits per pixel  24
Refresh Rate in Hz  60
Info    Display[42280620134498374] bounds=[0,0 1536x864], workarea=[0,0 1536x864], scale=1.25, rotation=0, panel_rotation=0 external.
Color space (all)   {primaries:BT709, transfer:IEC61966_2_1, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}
Buffer format (all) BGRA_8888
SDR white level in nits 100
Bits per color component    8
Bits per pixel  24
Refresh Rate in Hz  60
Video Acceleration Information
Encoding    
Vulkan Information
Device Performance Information
Log Messages
[9685:9685:0113/094257.115852:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(378)] : InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[9685:9685:0114/083906.479080:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(226)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
```

How to enable Hardware acceleration on my laptop?

Version: Ubuntu 21.04 with X11 (not wayland)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, video acceleration works only in X11 and not under Wayland. The issue comes down to [this open issue](https://github.com/intel/libva/issues/122) involving DRI3 support in `libva` 

Comment: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` --> x11. I don't use wayland. I disabled it because screensharing was not possible with wayland.

Comment: @guettli Changing a shell variable on a running system is not *"disabling Wayland"*. It requires reconfiguring your OS to start X11 instead of Wayland.  Maybe even installing X11 and all dependencies if they aren't pre-installed.

Comment: @svin83 you think I changed the env var? No, I did not. I switched to x11 some weeks ago, because there where issues with scree-sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware acceleration seems rather hit and miss with the Snap version of Chromium. If you are *not* using an Nvidia graphics adapter in your recent notebook, then the answer to your question about using hardware accelerated video encoding is a definite "maybe".

If you haven't already, take a look at the settings available in `chrome://flags`:

[image: Chromium - Available]

For my less-than-recent Lenovo X1 Carbon, there are a couple of options available. However, hardware accelerated video encoding is not one of them:

[image: Chromium - Unavailable]

If you are not wedded to the Snap version of Chromium and are open to using a Flathub installation, then you can choose between [the Chromium Browser and the "Ungoogled" Chromium Browser](https://flathub.org/apps/search/chromium) packages. These have support support for VA-API, OpenH264 and `libfdk-aac`, which are required for hardware acceleration on many systems.

Alternatively, there is [the Mint package](http://packages.linuxmint.com/search.php?release=una&section=any&keyword=chromium), which can be installed via `apt` [in up to seven steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1386740/1222991) on your Ubuntu system.