# Reliable source for Chromium deb file for Ubuntu Focal (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, chromium, selenium

Hope you are all doing well.

I am sure this is a frequently asked query, but asking from a different perspective.

I am looking for a reliable and secure source for Chromium browser (.deb) to be used in some development work mostly in a headless state only. Server is based on a customized version of Ubuntu 20.04 that does not have snaps installed. We are looking for an easy to download and use option like Google Chrome where we can download the .deb from the Google Website and install it directly [How to install Chrome browser properly via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line). This means no addition of any separate repos or messing with the source lists and pinning Chromium alone. Unfortunately I could not find any such options for the Chromium deb package.

All the options I have seen so far include snaps, flatpaks, deb package from Debian/Linux Mint/nix and random PPAs. No prejudice or anything regarding the options mentioned above except that seems a little complex to my limited experience.  Some PPAs are dated and not regularly maintained. Google Chrome is not being preferred due to its proprietary nature. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Thanks in Advance - Have a great day...

PS: My apologies if this is not the right forum for this query.

Comment: Hey rainingdistros! Why do you feel that snap package of Chromium won't be up to date? Also, installing snap packages is not as complicated as you think. Just run this in terminal: `sudo snap install chromium`.

Comment: The not up to date part was meant for the random PPAs part of the question - will update the question. And regarding snaps - we are using a very small customized version of Ubuntu 20.04 which does not have snap installed or its dependencies.

- thanks you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386738/how-to-install-chromium-from-the-linux-mint-repositories-in-ubuntu

Comment: @blade - thank you for your response - But I had already been through that link and had mentioned `All the options I have seen so far include snaps, flatpaks, deb package from Debian/Linux Mint/nix and random PPAs.` I was looking for something less complex... I hope the question does not get considered as duplicate...

Comment: @rainingdistros Gotcha, I'm afraid until Canonical stops pushing Snapcraft, it's just choosing the lesser evil. There's one more option I can think of, using a portable version, like one of these: https://chromium.woolyss.com/