# Why won't Chromium use dark mode?

Tags: google-chrome, themes, chromium, gtk

I have totally ran out of ideas as to why Chrome/Firefox both won't use my GTK theme which is set to dark. I've been messing around with trying to add `--force-dark-mode --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode` to the flags, but that doesn't appear to be working either. I don't know whether I'm doing it wrong or not.

I tried adding the following to `~/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini` and `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` as well.

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

That didn't work either.

Could anyone provide me with some advice as to how to get Chromium to use dark mode? I'm on pretty much a brand new installation of Ubuntu 22.04.02

EDIT: Changing the files I mentioned and rebooting solved the issue.

Comment: You could always just add a dark theme to it if there is one that matches:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes

Comment: This may be due to snap. Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386738/how-to-install-chromium-from-the-linux-mint-repositories-in-ubuntu and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401