# Is this link a good roadmap to remove SNAP?

Tags: snap

In order to free up more space on my filesystem root partition it was suggested
since I am not using anything specifically with SNAP [I only have the snap-store]
to go ahead and remove SNAP. This would free up about 4.5 GB of space. I am currently
at 90% on the partition.
This link:

[remove snap entirely by itsfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/remove-snap/#remove-snap-entirely-from-ubuntu-use-with-extreme-caution-)

seems to show in detail how to successfully, and hopefully uneventfully, get rid of SNAP.
I am interested in any input to the use of the itsfoss.com instructional.
thanks...

Comment: There are loads of posts on removing or disabling snap, including by Ubuntu *developers* found on Planet Ubuntu etc.. Given we don't know what OS/release you're using (*you didn't specify*) nor how you intend using your system into the future (*as there can be consequences into the future which can only be resolved by re-enabling snapd*) your question is currently unanswerable as is, let alone being largely seeking *opinion* which I see as off-topic here (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) given there is no actual problem to solve in your question.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1386738/124466

Comment: Well yes there is a problem. My partition is 90% full and I need to create space. I am running 20.04.6 LTS. I am not sure how to explain how I to intend to use my system going forward. It is a desktop computer in my home that can be used for a variety of reasons. Admittedly I was seeking an opinion on the efficacy of the ItsFoss instructional.on removing snapd. The links provided were helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove snap from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-from-ubuntu)