# Adding Linux Mint repos to Ubuntu

Tags: apt, snap, mint, add-apt-repository

I was just wondering if there's a way to add Linux Mint repos to Ubuntu to replace the apt commands that are rerouted to Snaps. For example, if I add the Mint repos, could I just do "sudo apt install firefox" or "sudo apt install chromium-browser" without the commands installing the Snap versions? If so, how could I do it and is it safe? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could certainly try --it's YOUR system-- but it might blow up on you. Nobody has tested to see if it's safe. You will be doing that testing. If it damages your system, then you are on your own. Our only advice will be to reinstall. See [Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1386738/124466

Comment: Don't forget *apt* & other package tools upgrade your system to the latest package available; which is what Linux Mint take advantage of in their repositories (ie. *inflating* package versions so they'll be used instead of Ubuntu packages).. ie. you'll have to do the *pinning* to ensure your system remains a *stable* Ubuntu system otherwise you'll be running Frakensystem as user535733 already suggested.  It's not as simple as adding sources (*unless a broken system is your intended purpose*).  Make notes of what you do as you'll likely break *release-upgrade* tools etc.. so plan on re-install.

Comment: Your question would have been better asked on a Forum in my opinion, rather than a Q&A site like this... ie. we can give *opinions* & *clues* on a forum (like https://ubuntuforums.org/ which is Ubuntu Forums) where they are off-topic on this site (*except as side-comment*) as Q&A sites are geared for a *problem* (the question) which is solved by *answers* where different *opinions* are presented by different answers (different ways of solving the problem). This isn't a forum don't forget.