# Chromium not opening in TigerVNC

Tags: 22.04, chromium, vnc

We have TigerVNC installed in a docker Ubuntu 22.04 setup. I have also installed Chromium deb package...

When I tried to open Vhromium from VNC using below command:

```
chromium --disable-dev-shm-usage --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --user-data-dir --window-position=0,0
```

Its stuck and not opening:

[image]

Is there anything extra to add here? We have TigerVNC installed and vncserver in running in DISPLAY:1.0

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a snap issue.

Remove Chromium snap with `sudo apt purge chromium-browser`.

Then, install Chromium using [APT](https://askubuntu.com/a/1386740/124466) and try again.

Comment: I followed the below approach.. It got installed.. but i am getting the same problem..  Now i have to use `sudo chromium` to open and i am getting an error

4248:4248:1027/131250.959755:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[4248:4248:1027/131250.959801:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

DISPLAY variable is already set :
echo $DISPLAY ->
:1.0