# Problems installing the Debian package for Chromium in Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, mint

I want to install the Debian package for Chromium ( from Linux Mint) instead of the Snap one offered for Xubuntu, because the Snap version does not work with KeePassXC. The Debian version from the Mint maintainers does work (al least it worked well with Xubuntu 20.04).
I tried to install Chromium as a Debian package following the instructions from [How to install Chromium from the Linux Mint repositories in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386738/how-to-install-chromium-from-the-linux-mint-repositories-in-ubuntu).

I issued these commands:

```
$ echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com victoria upstream" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint-victoria.list
$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A6616109451BBBF2
$ sudo apt update
$ cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-chromium
Package: *
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: chromium
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: 1000
EOF
```

These ones all went flawlessly. The next one made problems:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt install chromium
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/102 MB of archives.
After this operation, 323 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 223159 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium_121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chromium (121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium_121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop', which is also in package chromium-browser 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2.22.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium_121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$
```

(this is a repetition of the command to show English error messages, originally 102 MB were fetched).

The file `/var/cache/apt/archives/chromium_121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia_amd64.deb` exists. To assure that it came right, I manually downloaded another copy from  [http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/upstream/c/chromium/chromium_121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia_amd64.deb](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/upstream/c/chromium/chromium_121.0.6167.139%7Elinuxmint1+virginia_amd64.deb) and compared it to the other one: Their content was identical.
Nevertheless, I get this error message if I repeat `sudo apt install chromium`.
**How to proceed?**

Comment: "which is also in package chromium-browser": `apt remove chromium-browser && apt install chromium`?

Comment: which apparently is only a stub to install the not wanted Snap version instead. You are right, one first has to remove it!

Answer (score 2):

The comment gave the right hint: `dpkg -l` showed that there was some kind of `chromium-browser` installed (originally from the live stick):

```
$ dpkg -l | grep chromium
ii  chromium-browser                         1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2.22.04.1 amd64
Transitional package - chromium-browser -> chromium snap
$ chromium-browser --version

Command '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' requires the chromium snap to be installed.
Please install it with:
snap install chromium       # this is what I want to avoid!
$
```

So this package was merely a stub to install the snap version which I wanted to avoid! After I removed it by `sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser` everything went fine:

```
$ echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com victoria upstream" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint-victoria.list
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com victoria upstream
$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A6616109451BBBF
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DsWBHBRTjv/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A6616109451BBBF
gpg: "A6616109451BBBF" ist keine Schlüssel-ID: überspringe
gpg: Schlüssel 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel 40976EAF437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" nicht geändert
gpg: Schlüssel A1715D88E1DF1F24: "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Git Maintainers" nicht geändert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 3
gpg:              unverändert: 3
$ sudo apt update
OK:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
OK:2 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
OK:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
OK:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
OK:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu jammy InRelease
OK:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/giuspen/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
OK:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yktooo/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com una InRelease
OK:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:10 http://packages.linuxmint.com victoria InRelease
OK:11 http://packages.linuxmint.com una Release
OK:12 http://packages.linuxmint.com victoria Release
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Alle Pakete sind aktuell.
W: http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/una/Release.gpg: Schlüssel ist im veralteten Schlüsselbund trusted.gpg gespeichert (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), siehe den Abschnitt MISSBILLIGUNG in apt-key(8) für Details.
W: http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/victoria/Release.gpg: Schlüssel ist im veralteten Schlüsselbund trusted.gpg gespeichert (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), siehe den Abschnitt MISSBILLIGUNG in apt-key(8) für Details.
$ cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-chromium
Package: *
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: chromium
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: 1000
EOF
Package: *
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: -1
Package: chromium
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: 1000
$ sudo apt install chromium
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Das folgende Paket wurde automatisch installiert und wird nicht mehr benötigt:
gimp-help-common
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um es zu entfernen.
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
chromium
0 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 102 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 323 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 217914 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../chromium_121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von chromium (121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia) ...
chromium (121.0.6167.139~linuxmint1+virginia) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für man-db (2.10.2-1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
$ sudo apt autoremove
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
gimp-help-common
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Nach dieser Operation werden 23,6 kB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] J
(Lese Datenbank ... 218003 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit     installiert.)
Entfernen von gimp-help-common (2.10.0-1) ...
$
```

(sorry, I have forgotten to prepend the commands to get English messages).

Finally I got **Version 121.0.6167.139 (Offizieller Build) for Linux Mint (64-Bit)** this way.

There are several answers to my other question deprecated use of `apt-key`, which was a duplicate: [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key).

Bingo!