Snap Chromium don't work after update
Since 08.06.2024 update of Chromium (snap) on my Xubuntu 22.04 LTS, Chromium has stopped working. Also don't work Brave Browser (also snap), Video Downloader and some another program.
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/doc none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/usr/local/share": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/sphinx_rtd_theme /usr/share/sphinx_rtd_theme none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/sphinx_rtd_theme" because it would affect the host in "/var/lib/snapd"
[0617/050218.425775:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0617/050218.844031:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0617/050219.038354:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[6377:6377:0617/050222.541249:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=135

How to solve this problem?

Use APT Chromium https://askubuntu.com/q/1386738/124466

Maybe...I will try... But how about Brave Browser?

It is upto you what you want to use. Brave should have a .deb package in its website.

My favourite browser is Brave. Chromium I use for specific projects.

Have you tried uninstalling one of the snaps and then installing it, do it with something that isnot very special, like video downloader.

I tried. Reinstalled Brave and Chromium - but they don't work. I also type 'sudo snap refresh' - but also don't work.

Does your Firefox ever lag when opening a new tab?
