Chromium not working after upgrade to 22.04
When I click the icons of snap apps Application name appears next to Activities for 10 to 20 seconds and disappears...applications not opening...Its been two years :). I'm somehow opening chrome from command line but Ubuntu Software app is not opening
Debug outut
$SNAPD_DEBUG=1 dbus-launch snap run chromium
Unable to create /home/ubuntu18/.dbus/session-bus
2024/10/03 07:19:36.478608 logger.go:93: DEBUG: snap (at "/snap/snapd/current") is older ("2.56.2") than distribution package ("2.63+22.04ubuntu0.1")
2024/10/03 07:19:36.481836 logger.go:93: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"start", "time":"1727920176.481827"}
2024/10/03 07:19:36.492583 logger.go:93: DEBUG: executing snap-confine from /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
2024/10/03 07:19:36.509556 logger.go:93: DEBUG: SELinux not enabled
2024/10/03 07:19:36.520599 logger.go:93: DEBUG: creating transient scope snap.chromium.chromium
2024/10/03 07:19:36.521557 logger.go:93: DEBUG: using session bus
2024/10/03 07:19:36.525852 logger.go:93: DEBUG: StartTransientUnit failed with "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited": [Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
2024/10/03 07:19:36.531816 logger.go:93: DEBUG: snapd cannot track the started application
2024/10/03 07:19:36.531877 logger.go:93: DEBUG: snap refreshes will not be postponed by this process
2024/10/03 07:19:36.531927 logger.go:93: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap to snap-confine", "time":"1727920176.531920"}
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine enter", "time":"1727920176.537150"}
DEBUG: umask reset, old umask was   02
DEBUG: security tag: snap.chromium.chromium
DEBUG: executable:   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec
DEBUG: confinement:  non-classic
DEBUG: base snap:    core22
DEBUG: ruid: 1000, euid: 0, suid: 0
DEBUG: rgid: 1000, egid: 1000, sgid: 1000
DEBUG: apparmor label on snap-confine is: /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
DEBUG: apparmor mode is: enforce
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine mount namespace start", "time":"1727920176.538083"}
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope (global), uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: ensuring that snap mount directory is shared
DEBUG: unsharing snap namespace directory
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: releasing lock 5
DEBUG: opened snap-update-ns executable as file descriptor 5
DEBUG: opened snap-discard-ns executable as file descriptor 6
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/chromium.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope chromium, uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: initializing mount namespace: chromium
**
DEBUG: device cgroup not required due to base core22
DEBUG: setting up device cgroup, mode "optional"
**
DEBUG: libudev has current tags support
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0 has matching current tag
DEBUG: get bpf object at path /sys/fs/bpf/snap/snap_chromium_chromium
DEBUG: found existing device map
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: found 22 existing entries in devices map
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:8
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 137:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 138:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 226:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 226:128
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:9
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:3
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 142:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:7
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:2
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 136:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:5
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 10:242
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 249:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 10:239
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 143:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 139:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 141:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 10:200
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 140:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: load program of type 0xf, 33 instructions
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:3
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:5
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:7
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:8
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:9
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:1
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:2
DEBUG: v2 allow c 136:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 137:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 138:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 139:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 140:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 141:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 142:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 143:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 10:239
DEBUG: v2 allow c 10:200
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dri/card0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 226:0
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-DVI-D-1 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-DVI-D-1
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/renderD128 has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dri/renderD128
DEBUG: v2 allow c 226:128
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/virtual/dma_heap/system has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dma_heap/system
DEBUG: v2 allow c 249:0
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/virtual/mem/full has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/full
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:7
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/virtual/misc/rfkill has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/rfkill
DEBUG: v2 allow c 10:242
DEBUG: device /sys/module/rfkill has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/module/rfkill
**
DEBUG: process in cgroup /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not a snap cgroup
**

I highlighted cgroup lines thinking they are the problem
Android Studio, PyCharm CE are also snaps, but surprisingly opening properly
But again "Ubuntu Software" snap is not opening

This like might have the answer to your problem: - https://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/snap-problem-solving.html

Didn't fix the issue...How do I reverse the DBUS setting mentioned in the link btw...I mean, reverse $export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus". Previous value was unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-hrXNIzHxOA,guid=fdde64d70b1a199cfffc568666fe7444. Or should I leave it as it is

Installing Chromium as a .deb package may fix the issue. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1386740/124466

That's not the right way...I have to copy multiple profiles data, like bookmarks, history etc...This is a simple error...but the people with knowledge about all these cgroups and buses are busy I guess

Actually there are couple of other snaps also facing same problem...most important of them is Ubuntu Software...For this only I need it...Chromium I found workaround (opening from command line)..I don't know how to open Ubuntu Software from command line...I am stuck
