# How to force a application to use the right GTK version save dialog box

Tags: unity, themes, chromium, gtk

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2, the long term support version, with unity/lightdm, and Chromium browser from the debian archives. Everything works great except for a couple of native integrations, for example the file chooser in the application seems corrupted, like it is using a gtk3 calling convention but the code that is executing is gtk4. It is like this [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328516/force-chromium-to-use-dolphin-file-manager-to-save-a-download) except that I am not running that desktop environment, so i am looking for a general answer.

here is what my screen looks like normally:

[image: desktop environment - chromium window and sidebar]

and here is what my save dialog box looks like:

[image]

The problem manifests a lot like the *other question* linked above: when i type a filename, it searches instead.

Does this require Chromium to be compiled against a different GTK version? Is there such a distribution out there?

Comment: looks like it at least handles typing correctly on ubuntu 22.10 - got that from here - https://old.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/y98iup/ubuntu_unity_2210_well_done_rudra/

Comment: Additional info for the question needs to be added with edit not as a comment. All info for the question in one place.

Comment: If GTKv3 vs. v4 were really the issue, then you would fix the source code and recompile. While there are runtime ways to accomplish what you suggest (like an AppArmor rule), those seem inappropriate: Bugs should be fixed instead of intrusively worked around.

Comment: but then how does the snap version seen to work fine? it seems to me that they somehow isolate what ldd sees for an application and then it picks the right one. maybe they also change the source code in order to lock people into using their uniquely gtk3 compatible build...