# Can Ubuntu Server be suitable for desktop use?

Tags: server, ppa, gui

I wish to use a minimal Ubuntu install with the latest stable Pantheon desktop because the performance of Elementary OS 6 is sub par due to the large size of the pre installed flatpak apps. Is Ubuntu server minimal enough to have any real performance impact. Will removing the Snap Packaging Format break the system?

Answer (score 2):

> Can Ubuntu Server be suitable for desktop use?

Yes. You can install a desktop environment in Ubuntu server, and use it in a desktop computer.

> Is Ubuntu server minimal enough to have any real performance impact.

Ubuntu Server does not have the GNOME desktop preinstalled, so you will not have many unnecessary background processes, and the performance should be better.

> Will removing the Snap Packaging Format break the system?

No, it should not. Here's [how to](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466) completely (and safely) remove snap. However, you will need special measures to [install](https://askubuntu.com/q/1204571/124466) Chromium.

> I wish to use a minimal Ubuntu install with the latest stable Pantheon desktop

To install Pantheon desktop, add the [Elementary Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eelementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

Finally, install the relevant metapackage for elementary desktop.

```
sudo apt install elementary-meta
```

Comment: Archisman Will pantheon work if I install elementary-minimal?

Comment: I don't know. Several websites say that `elementary-meta` and `elementary-desktop` should work. Also, `elementary-meta` installs more packages than `elementary-desktop`.