# Webdriver error from Selenium on Google Colab

Tags: python, google, selenium

I'm creating a scraper on google colab using Selenium but now doesnt work. Yes in the past but I dont know why now doesn't.

The code is:

```
#dependencies
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install fake-useragent
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

#options to chromedriver
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent="'+userAgent+'"')
```

When a I run this code, colab show the next error:

"Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1"

Do you know any solution? I've looked for an answer on other related topics but nothing works for me

I found some answers here: [How to install Chromium without snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap)

"..was the result of an issue induced as the colab system was updated from v18.04 to ubuntu v20.04 LTS and with Ubuntu v20.04 LTS google-colaboratory no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of a snap package..."

but I'd like to use Google Colaboratory, its already possible?