# How to Recover Firefox Configuration With Flapak?

Tags: firefox, flatpak

I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04, and therefore, the default firefox was uninstalled (since I uninstalled snap). Nevertheless, the profiles seem to be present:

```
reichelt@reichelt-desktop:~$ ls .mozilla/firefox/
'Crash Reports'   gaa7jeep.default   installs.ini   key4.db   logins.json  'Pending Pings'   profiles.ini
```

Since I don't use snap, according to the answer to [How to install Chromium without snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap/1258911#1258911), I installed firefox with flatpak by downloading the flapakref and installing using `flatpak install org.mozilla.firefox.flatpakref`. This is working like a charm, but my history, logins etc. are lost.

Is there any way to import the old profile? Due to a hint of ChatGPT, I tried using the `-profile` parameter of flatpak by `flatpak run org.mozilla.firefox -profile /home/reichelt/.mozilla/firefox/gaa7jeep.default/`, but this results in `Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.` It seems like the access right to the profile folder is missing.

Is there a way to fix it, or a general way to reuse the old folder?

Comment: Workaround: You can install Firefox as a [traditional .deb package](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466), which will preserve your bookmarks. Also, later on, you can sign in to Firefox to sync everything.

Comment: Please note that chatgpt generated content are [usually wrong](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20298/124466), and banned in Ask Ubuntu. https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20209/124466 Please consider removing the image

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've removed the image.