How to install Chromium browser without snap or flatpak in Ubuntu 24.04?
I am looking for a way to install Chromium without snap or flatpak in Ubuntu 24.04.
This answer would not work because Debian buster is too old.
I thought about adding Debian bookworm, but Debian bookworm does not have t64 libraries, while Ubuntu 24.04 uses t64 libraries.
For example, the debian repository is trying to pull libzzip-0-13 as a dependency, but Ubuntu already has libzzip-0-13t64.
So, is there any way to install Chromium without snap or flatpak? Perhaps using Debian Trixie repository or some PPA?

Please use this as a reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap/1511695#1511695   it has all kinds of answers.

@Rinzwind none of the top voted answer (except your answer) work. They are all about beta chromium or google chrome, or flatpak. That is why I asked this question

Yeah I noticed. Mine will maybe float to the top in about a year.  My answer is UNOFFICIAL. https://launchpad.net/~xtradeb/+archive/ubuntu/apps   If you see the list of packages they have they could make their own Ubuntu-apt-only :D

Use apt?!
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xtradeb/apps -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install chromium



Better to post this as an answer to https://askubuntu.com/q/1204571/158442 as well so that remains the canonical post for Chromium without snap
